# 406 Not Acceptable only in Safari

Tags: http, safari, http-status-codes, http-status-code-406, http-status

```
406 Not Acceptable    
An appropriate representation of the requested resource / could not be found on this server.
```

I migrated servers from hostgator to dedicated. Now, a blank index.html page is throwing this error ONLY in safari (desktop & mobile). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the HTTP requests sent by different servers (in particular the Accept header field).